# How can I assign pixel values of an image to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to import an image and the store all the pixel values in an array. How can I do this ?

This is what I have tried already but the array is wrong.

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('red-flower.jpg', 'r')
pix_val = list(im.getdata())
```

Comment: Use `numpy.array(im.getdata())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameters wrong for `Image.open()`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('red-flower.jpg')
array = np.array(im)
```

Documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class).